# Turn on Text Replacement, Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, auto-complete

I know I'm supposed to enable text replacement via Edit > Substitutions > Text Replacement but… I cannot find that menu in Chrome at all. Help?

Comment: Re-opening this issue so someone will finally fix it once and for all... Please reply and let Google know if you’ve also suffered from this problem. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=677537

Comment: @JonathanA.Levi You can't reopen a question by posting a comment.  To add attention to a question you need to [open a bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).  To do that you have to offer [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), and it doesn't look like you have enough.  You can gain reputation by asking and answering questions that others will vote on.

Comment: @fsb looks like they're referring to reopening an issue on another website, right?

Comment: @DanRosenstark I'm not sure, he made the same comment on another Chrome question, too.  I'm thinking he just needs help and is looking for others to pressure Google into fixing this.  But I could be wrong...

Comment: This works only for inboxed apps and apps downloaded from App Store, It will work in Mail, Notes, Safari, but not Outlook, Chrome, etc.

Answer (score 17):

This is currently not possible because Chrome does few things its own way. Here is the bug that tracks this

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42434

Still if you dream about adding a comment there forget it, even if Chromium is Open-Source the team decided that they don't need external feedback and disabled the commenting.

There is also a thread on Google Forums about this bug. But again, Google closed the topic in order to avoid other comments.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/CAv_4eUkhzk

I guess that your only option would be use Twitter to tween about this issue. Be use that you mention `@Google` in your tweet. You will be surprised how reactive are big companies when their PR is affected by their poor experience.

Comment: I'm hopeful that this will be resolved eventually. [Another bug has been opened](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=716099) with 42434 listed as a blocker. The last comment in this more recent issue is, "Text prediction is being worked on right now. Once that's completed, we'll move on to emoji keyboard. Keep in mind, working with text in the web contents is difficult, so it will take some time."

Comment: Moved to Firefox more than 6mo ago and happy since!

Comment: How do you manage text replacement within Firefox?

Answer (score 6):

Enter in terminal to activate text replacement across all applications:

```
defaults write -g WebAutomaticTextReplacementEnabled -bool true
```

Comment: Thanks. The command ran with no problem, I restarted Chrome, but still... no dice. Is this correct for Yosemite?

Comment: Hmm, maybe this only automatically enables it for all supported application. Which chrome doesn't seem to be since it does not have the menu like you said. It seems to be a known issue, there are a few posts about it on the internet.

Comment: Yes, it's only for apps that support the feature (ie. apps that already have the _Substitutions_ option in the _Edit_ menu. This terminal command just saves you the trouble of switching it on for all the apps that support it.

Answer (score 4):

That feature appears to be specific to Safari on OS X; however, there are plenty of extensions for Chrome that imitate that functionality (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-text-expander-for-go/iibninhmiggehlcdolcilmhacighjamp?hl=en for example).  It will not use the built-in OS X dictionary, unfortunately, but can sync dictionaries across Chrome browsers on the same account.

Comment: These a NOT specific to Safari and they are supposed to work with any application on OS X. This is a OS level functionality which can be enabled or disabled for specific apps if you want. Still, Chrome is doing something very-different which is breaking this. Chrome is the only app where this feature does not work.

Comment: Note:  The web extensions that do this in chrome have to by nature have very broad rights to everything you type and see while browsing, so you may want to weight the added value of substitutions against the extra security risk.

Comment: This works only for inboxed apps and apps downloaded from App Store, It will work in Mail, Notes, Safari, but not Outlook, Chrome, etc.