# Text substitution does not work with Slack on Yosemite

Tags: macos, keyboard, system-settings, slack

I have a text substitution setup within the System Preferences. This works most places within OS X as far as I can tell, but it does not work in [Slack](https://slack.com/). (Their native app for OS X version 1.1.4 - 2814)

Does anyone know why?

[image]

**UPDATE**
It looks like this is not specific to Slack at all

Comment: Are you using a slack application (if so what version and name) or a browser (if so what version and name)?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. I'm using the official Slack client for Mac OS X, version 1.1.4 (2814).

Comment: If you have Chrome, does it work there? Slack uses the same engine.

Comment: No, it doesn't work in Chrome either, so it looks like it's more likely to be a Chrome issue?

Comment: Wow, man. I came here because my substitution of shrugs not working in Slack. :) The only difference is that my shortcut is '\/' (two slashes)

Comment: 2nd "wow": It looks like the substitution do work in native slack app, only UI part is broken and not shown. I believe if you write `&shrug;` in slack text area and hit spacebar the replacement will occur.

Comment: Ok, this is hilarious. I found this post while experiencing the same issue - down to the specific replacement! The only difference is that my input token is `:shrug`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activate the "Text Replacement" option in the edit menu.

[image: option to activate text replacement]

Comment: Don't have such menu items for Slack "2.6.1 Direct Download" and macOS Sierra 10.12.4 (16E195) :(

Comment: not present in 3.0.5 direct download either. using @tbizzle's answer and restarting client worked.

Comment: As of Slack 3.0.5, accepted answer seems deprecated. The option in the menu is no longer available.

Answer (score 14):

Even after following the instructions in the accepted answer, this still did not work for me until I followed [these](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179202/84638) instructions. Basically, run the following in a terminal:

`defaults write -g WebAutomaticTextReplacementEnabled -bool true`

or to only change Slack's behavior (and not pollute your global domain):

`defaults write com.tinyspeck.slackmacgap WebAutomaticTextReplacementEnabled -bool true`

Comment: don't forget to restart the client after doing this- then it appears to work fine!

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer as of September 2022.

Comment: This isn't working for me. Just me?

Comment: This doesn't for me either on Monterey 12.6.1 and Slack 4.29.149

Comment: This worked for me on Ventura 13.3.1 - didn't even have to restart the client.

Answer (score 3):

So, it seems that [Text Substitutions have not been implemented in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42434) so I assume that is the underlying problem I'm having with Slack.

Comment: @carrieje's answer is correct. You don't have to wait for Chrome to implement anything!