# Quick combination or text replacement for typing schwa

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, text-input, spelling

I would like to configure a simple key combination to type a schwa (ǝ). I configured text replacement for the å character, but it won't work if it's inside a word i.e. "å" gets replaced correctly to "ǝ", but "andatå" doesn't become "andatǝ". Good solutions would be:

- automatic text replacement for the å character
- a way to assign ǝ to the option+a key combination

My keyboard has the Italian ISO layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve the first, as you'd have to have one instance for each word in which it occurs. As you've discovered, the text replacer needs a space before & after.

The second idea could be done using [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) & designing your own replacement keyboard layout. It's not an app I'm terribly experienced with, but I have managed to make my own modified structure without too much learning curve.
you end up with a 'new' layout copied from your existing one…

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a replacement under: System Preferences > Keyboard > Text

And then for ex: add `schwa === ǝ`

(To enable this in the browser [see this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179187/turn-on-text-replacement-chrome/179202#179202?newreg=9818870d608548b79865c2ece3114efc).)