# Subscript, super script, and special symbols as Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut

I need to write a statistical paper. So I need to use subscripts and superscripts, often with in the same alphabet. For example X^2 at time "t", time "t-1" etc. I also need to type special symbols like beta, theta, alpha etc.
This is possible in Microsoft Word I am aware, but i often use a note taking app like notability to jot down my notes before transferring them into the final draft.

For apps like that you need to harcode the symbol and the keyboard shortcut in the "keyboards" in system preferences.

1. Is there a way to add these subscripted and superscripted versions of alphabets and numbers to that window?
2. If the above is fulfilled, Is there a way I can do this without having to type out each in the characters in the keyboard window, and instead upload everything from a previously created file?

Comment: You can build your own keyboard layout - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/413103/quick-combination-or-text-replacement-for-typing-schwa

Comment: For casual x²⁽ᵗ⁻¹⁾ it is possible to use Emoji & Symbols.

Comment: Presumably you will use a real equation editor for your actual paper.  I don’t think what you create using a custom keyboard would normally be directly transferable to such an editor, you would have to do it all again.